# Xamarin.Forms (Android) Fileprovider Tag in manifest is causing app to crash on start

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I want to bind a library to open the camera on xamarin.forms projects. But I am stuck on putting the provider into the manifest. Without the `<provider>` content, it launches fine, but this is needed in order to access the cam. What is causing the crash?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app4" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />



  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <application android:label="App4.Android" android:theme="@style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">



    <!-- ADD FILE PROVIDER HERE -->
    <provider android:name="Android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="Android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>



  </application>

</manifest>
```

Error message at launch:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider Android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.app4-d3ayAGdJtY4q5btMMbcypw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.app4-d3ayAGdJtY4q5btMMbcypw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.companyname.app4-d3ayAGdJtY4q5btMMbcypw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]'
```

Comment: `android` is not capitalized in either `android:name` attribute value in the `<provider>` and `<meta-data>` tags.

Comment: Note that when you need to write XML tags in Stack Overflow questions, they need to be `<formatted>` so that they appear. They will otherwise be rendered as (invalid) HTML. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mike M. said, you could try the provider like below:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
  android:authorities="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider" 
  android:exported="false" 
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

Comment: Heya, thank you. This made it work. 
I fail to understand what is different here. I left out the authorities line and used mine instead and it works. Where was my mistake?